# Is it possible to update only EE core by CE core?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, ee-1.13, migration

We have bought Magento EE more than year ago. Now we decided to break the contract couse it too expensive for us.

At the same time we can still use EE but without any support certainly.

I have read that EE and CE has the same core. If it does - the main idea is to replace EE core files by CE core files to update magento. And after that to change the theme.

Is it possible to use EE functionality and be updated by CE at the same time? We would like to use EE functionality and have up-to-date CE core at the same time.

**UPDATE:**

I didn't tell why we need to do that. We have more than 200k products and more than 1000 categories. So I have heard that Varnish + CE is not stable. FPC - is a native magento cache system which works good. Therefore it would be good to use it in CE. Is there some way to migrate just FPC to CE?

Comment: This post might be a start: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6706/how-to-migrate-from-enterprise-edition-to-community-edition

Comment: Thanks for the link. But i wouldn't like to migrate to CE. I just want to upgrade partially EE core by CE. So it seems almost impossible.

Answer (score 1):

In theory this should be possible. 
basically EE is just CE + some modules.
You can update the CE part of EE, but there is a risk.
Just like any other extension, one that is part of EE may not be compatible with the new CE version.  But I guess you have to test before upgrading a live website.

An upgrade like this should be simple. Copy the new version if CE over the old version of EE. You might want to skip `Mage.php` and then, test, test, test.
oh...and backup everything before you start.

Comment: Except for the passwords being broken because EE uses a salt and CE doesn't. Since you have your hands on EE code, do a module rewrite to convert CE to using EE password storage and authentication.

Comment: I think in this case it won't be a problem because the EE encryption model will still exist. This is not about downgrading to ce. It is about keeping ee but upgrading only the ce modules.

Comment: I think anyone trying that will hate themselves on the next major version upgrade, but as my grandmother says, "Live in hope, die in despair". Though not having a $14,000 yearly fee might allow putting up with quite a bit of annoyance. Thank heavens for dev servers.

Comment: @FiascoLabs. I already stated in my answer that at some point the EE modules might stop working if you upgrade only the CE part. This is a risk. But in theory it could work.