# Magento Enterprise edition

Tags: magento-enterprise

I have a license for the Magento Enterprise edition that expires December 1, 2014. I haven't determined whether I need the Enterprise edition, and think the Community Edition might serve my needs. What happens when the license expires? And is there a month-to-month option?

Answer (score 1):

This should provide you with some information pertaining to migrating from EE to CE.

[How to migrate from Enterprise edition to Community Edition?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6706/how-to-migrate-from-enterprise-edition-to-community-edition)

Answer (score 1):

The licensing thing is only about license, not about running code. You are not allowed to run an EE installation without paying your license.

But as you might find out while googling is downgrading from EE to CE a pain.

Answer (score 0):

- Nothing will happen with your code and current Enterprise features!
  But, they'll stop providing the support you were getting for
  enterprise edition.
- You should contact Magento for their Pricing and plans (whether they support month-to-month option)