# Magento Database Separation

Tags: magento-enterprise, database, mysql, magento-community, migration

We've been running Magento Enterprise with 30 different store views all sharing the same catalog and attributes.  We're now getting ready to spin of most of the store-views into seperate installs of Magento Community Edition.

How can I take the mySQL backup from the enterprise setup and import the products, attributes, customers into a community single store-view database?

Comment: I recommend @mam08ixo's approach. Create a new Magento instance with your backup, remove all of the websites you don't need, remove data (customers, products, categories, etc.) you don't need, etc. Systematic removal of data can be achieved by a Magento shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of extracting and restoring the data you need, my first approach would probably be to copy the whole database and then get rid of the data you *do not* need.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @maxm08ixo that was a great way to approach the problem. I took you advice and also found this old thread http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6706/how-to-migrate-from-enterprise-edition-to-community-edition