# "Encryption" Class Not Found When Downgrading From EE to CE

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise

I have followed the tutorial on [blog.yanted.com](http://blog.yanted.com/2014/02/21/downgrading-magento-enterprise-to-community/) and everything seems to be working except for I can not sign in the front or backend. I have copied `app/code/core/Enterprise/Pci/Model/Encryption.php` to `app/code/local/ClientName/Pci/Model/Encryption.php` and added the following code. The error I get is `Fatal error: Class 'ClientName_Pci_Model_Encryption' not found in /path/includes/src/__default.php on line 18430`. Most of what I read says it is a typo but I do not see any... Maybe worth noting I am on Magento 1.7, which seemed to correspond with the release date of my EE version.

app/code/local/ClientName/Pci/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <ClientName_Pci>
            <version>1.11.0.0</version>
        </ClientName_Pci>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
           <clientname_pci>
                <class>ClientName_Pci_Helper_Data</class>
            </clientname_pci>
            <core>
              <encryption_model>ClientName_Pci_Model_Encryption</encryption_model>
            </core>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

I then enabled it with app/etc/modules/ClientName_Pci.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
     <modules>
        <ClientName_Pci>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </ClientName_Pci>
     </modules>
</config>
```

My Encryption model starts out with this (for reference to ClientName):

```
<?php

class ClientName_Pci_Model_Encryption extends Mage_Core_Model_Encryption
{
```

Finally, I added this Helper/Data.php file in app/code/local/ClientName/Pci/Helper/ because I read a few places it was sometimes needed.

```
<?php

class ClientName_Pci_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I believe this is because the encryption types are different. Unless you unencrypt and encrypt using this new method, it won't match. I ended up having customers reset their passwords. My client was a < $10mil client and they were fine with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
/path/includes/src/__default.php
```

This is a file generated by the Magento compiler and it has not compiled your new source file yet. You should disable the compiler, recompile and then enable it again.

Or better, disable the compiler and keep it disabled. See: [When should I use the Magento Compiler](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/when-should-i-use-the-magento-compiler)

Comment: A compile, clear, disable or recompile did not solve the issue.