# Fatal error: Call to a member function getEntityTypeId() on a non-object in /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Url.php

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, error

I have downgrade the magento from ee to ce edition but , while indexing i am facing this issue .does any one have solution for this.

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function getEntityTypeId() on a non-object in /vagrant/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Url.php on line 585
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0043  263432  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.0086  296440  Mage::run( )    .../index.php:103
3   0.0377  487576  Mage_Core_Model_App->run( ) .../Mage.php:684
4   6.6529  3158576 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch( )  .../App.php:365
5   6.6765  3245912 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match( )   .../Front.php:172
6   6.6991  3464208 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch( ) .../Standard.php:254
7   11.9966 6641320 Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction( ) .../Action.php:418
8   12.0678 7160720 Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything( )  .../ProcessController.php:127
9   12.0755 7221192 Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll( ) .../Process.php:260
10  12.1271 7370056 Mage_Catalog_Model_Indexer_Url->reindexAll( )   .../Process.php:212
11  12.1457 8003408 Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites( )  .../Url.php:257
12  12.2368 8925424 Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites( )  .../Url.php:248
13  12.5461 9140848 Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshProductRewrites( )   .../Url.php:255
14  12.5570 9143416 Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Url->getProductsByStore( )  .../Url.php:538
15  12.5570 9144040 Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Url->_getProducts( )    .../Url.php:1033
16  12.6551 9745384 Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Url->_getProductAttribute( )    .../Url.php:997
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've deleted the product url_key by running something like:

```
DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE backend_model LIKE 'enterprise_%';
```

Can you check your eav_attribute table?

```
mysql> select * from eav_attribute where attribute_code="url_key"\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
   attribute_id: 35
 entity_type_id: 3
 attribute_code: url_key
attribute_model: NULL
  backend_model: catalog/category_attribute_backend_urlkey
   backend_type: varchar
  backend_table: NULL
 frontend_model: 
 frontend_input: text
 frontend_label: URL Key
 frontend_class: 
   source_model: 
    is_required: 0
is_user_defined: 0
  default_value: 
      is_unique: 0
           note: 
*************************** 2. row ***************************
   attribute_id: 86
 entity_type_id: 4
 attribute_code: url_key
attribute_model: NULL
  backend_model: catalog/product_attribute_backend_urlkey
   backend_type: varchar
  backend_table: NULL
 frontend_model: 
 frontend_input: text
 frontend_label: URL Key
 frontend_class: 
   source_model: 
    is_required: 0
is_user_defined: 0
  default_value: 
      is_unique: 0
           note: 
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yanted's guide deletes that product url_key from the eav_attribute table. I had to manually re-add attribute_id 86 to the table (exactly as Phil's results show above for the second row). Just add that row back in to the table, refresh, then reindex.