# magento 1 enterprise to magento 2 community

Tags: magento2, upgrade, migration, magento-1.14

Is it possible to migrate from Magento 1 Enterprise to Magento 2 Community edition? Or is the preferred way to migrate from Magento 1 Enterprise to Magento 1 Community and then to Magento 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going from EE 1.x to CE 1.x to CE 2.x will be more straightforward than direct from EE 1.x to CE 2.x. Going direct would involve modifying the data migration tool configuration to ignore enterprise table/columns, and removing EE references (attribute models, etc.) in the process.

Follow this post or the linked guide to go from EE 1.x to CC 1.x: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/6708/1905 That's a fairly straightforward process.

Once you have a stable CE 1.x install running, then you can move to Magento 2.x via the official data migration tool. Docs on that are here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html

Comment: if i move from EE 1.x to CE 1.x then which CE 1.x version i need to use ? because EE and CE both have different version.

Comment: @Camit1dk That's a completely different question, but EE 1.13 is equivalent to CE 1.8, and EE 1.14 is equivalent to CE 1.9.

Comment: Thank you @Ryan