# Migration from Magento 1.x EE to Magento 2.1.x CE

Tags: magento2, database, magento2-migration-tool

I have a project on Magento 1.14.3.1 EE and meed to migrate it to Magento 2.1.5 CE to test out the performance improvement the Magento 2.1.x version has to offer.

I was hoping to use the [Magento's Data Migration Tool](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool)

Currently I see there are only 3 migration flows available:

1. Magento 1.x CE - Magento 2.x CE
2. Magento 1.x EE - Magento 2.x EE
3. Magento 1.x CE - Magento 2.x EE

I was wondering if **Magento 1.x EE - Magento 2.x CE** is possible with this tool. If yes, is there any configuration we need adjust for this to work

Comment: Hey. Do you got any solution. Do suggest to me  also?

Comment: Some where I found a lengthy way to Migrate from M1 EE -> M1 CC -> M2 CC. But Not tried it.

Comment: @AhmadVaqasKhan If you can provide the URL or link to the materials that would be really helpful :)

Comment: It was not any material but a suggestion.. But I am in search of a better way.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134531/magento-1-enterprise-to-magento-2-community

Comment: The Data Migration Tool comes with a set of config files tailored to the flows you have mentioned. But have you thought of creating your on set of config files based on the ones that comes by default? At the end of the day the tool only asks you to specify the config.xml path file to use, it does not necessarily need to be a default one.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I have researched a lot for migration of **M1 Enterprise  to M2 Community** as **Data migration tool** allows you following migrations:

> ce-to-ce
>   ce-to-ee
>   ee-to-ee

Best approach would be migration from:
M1 EE -> M1 CE
M1 CE -> M2 CE (Through Data Migration Tool)

You have to keep in mind that you have to create all the Custom Modules and Theming for M2.  I have done this migration through following steps.

- Install a new Magento Instance say M1 CE 1.9.2.4 version.
- Make a Copy of Database used in M1 EE.
- Replace the Copy DB in M1 CE version.
- Now you will face several errors and you need to fix those as per the reports.Say deleting/Updating fields from eav_attribute table.
- You will face some errors in Admin Customer,Catalog ,Category Sections.
- M1 EE to M1 CE helpful article - https://www.brihaspatitech.com/blog/migrating-from-magento-enterprise-to-magento-community-version-successfully/
- After fixing all these errors Start the **Data Migration process from M1 CE to M2 CE** through data migration tool.
- In M2 CE version you need to create your custom modules and theme.
- Further Need to work on Magento Password Technique (as its different for community and enterprise) – Ahmad Vaqas Khan 6 mins ago   edit
- Also need to work on wishlist as it table structure different from community.

Hope this solution is helpful.

Comment: Further Need to work on Magento Password Technique (as its different for community and enterprise)

Comment: Also Wishlist section